# FET electrode convention?

Tags: schematics, layout, fet, electrode

Are there any conventions that allow one to tell which electrode is source and which one is drain?

[image: Standard logic buffer]

Comment: All FETs invert to drain as the output and source to appropriate rail P to + N to -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a standard CMOS inverter, the PMOS source would be on VCC and the NMOS source would be VSS.

The drains would be the output.

Comment: You just kind of have to know based on how they work.

Comment: The device itself is pretty symmetric and will work in either direction. It is the way it is biased that determines which is the drain and which is the source.

Comment: @KevinWhite Are you talking about actual JFETs? I don't think these are CMOS despite the symbol used.

Comment: @DKNguyen - the diagram shows a CMOS inverter. Devices in CMOS ICs are pretty symmetric. Since the substrate is connected to the most negative voltage around (depending upon doping) they don't have the body diode that annoys us with discrete devices. JFETS are also pretty symmetric although the junction is closer to source than drain.

Comment: @KevinWhite I see.

Comment: @KevinWhite Typo: I meant "I think these are CMOS, not JFET, despite the symbol used."